# Vertx: How to include additional files

Tags: html, server, vert.x

I am writing a vertx.io web server and am trying to create a simple web reponse, consisting of a web page. I have managed to send index.html, which is displayed. How do I add additional files, such as JavaScript and CSS files, so that a full webpage can be displayed? Or preferably, send the files once, since they will not change.

```
RouteMatcher routeMatcher = new RouteMatcher().get("/", new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServerRequest httpServerRequest) {
        httpServerRequest.response().sendFile("src/web/index.html");
    }
});

vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(routeMatcher).listen(8181, "localhost");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RouteMatcher httpRouteMatcher = new RouteMatcher().get("/", new
Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(final HttpServerRequest request) {
        request.response().sendFile("web/chat.html");
    }
}).get(".*\\.(css|js)$", new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(final HttpServerRequest request) {
        request.response().sendFile("web/" + new File(request.path()));
    }
});
```